# oracle sql join with listAgg , using switch case

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query with multiple joins and listagg as follows;

```
select c.case_id caseId, c.last_name lastName, c.first_name firstName,  
 listagg(lkp_cs.descr,',') within group (order by lkp_cs.id) as caseStatus
 from cases c join lkP_alt lkp_alt
 on c.ATL = lkp_alt.id
 join  case_status cs
 ON cs.case_id = c.case_id
 join lkp_case_status lkp_cs
 on lkp_cs.id = cs.case_status_id
 join users u  
 ON 
    ((c.created_by is not null and c.assigned_to is null 
    and c.created_by = u.id) 
    or 
    (c.assigned_to is not null 
    and c.assigned_to = u.id)) 
 left outer join users_unit uu 
 on uu.user_id = u.id 
 and c.delete_date is null
 group by c.case_id, c.edipi, c.last_name, c.first_name
```

lkp_cs.descr -> can have values like Active, Suspended, Renewed, Revoked, Closed, Deleted, Active A1, Active A3, Suspended Ext, Closed Ext...

There can be multiple status for a case. But when one of the status is closed then it should just return Closed. I can pull the values but for UI prespective i should display only Closed status.
I do not want to do it in UI though. I tried case but didnt work. Can someone suggest how to do?

Output rightnow is:

```
caseId  lastName    firstName   caseStatus                      
 100    AAA         BBB         Active, Active A1, Renewed
 101    CCC         DDD         Active, Active A1, Renewed, Closed
 102    CCC         DDD         Active, Active A1, Renewed, Closed Ext
```

This should change to:

```
caseId  lastName    firstName   caseStatus                      
 100    AAA         BBB         Active, Active A1, Renewed
 101    CCC         DDD         Closed
 102    CCC         DDD         Closed Ext
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `case` expression:

```
(case when sum(case when case when lkp_cs.descr = 'closed' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
      then 'closed'
      else listagg(lkp_cs.descr,',') within group (order by lkp_cs.id)
 end) as caseStatus
```

Comment: something is wrong with the syntax. can you please check

Comment: getting ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 9

Comment: @JNPW . . . An extra `sum()` sneaked into there ;)